How to manage topics in FCM REST API?
I am using Cloudflare Workers which are not fully compatible with NodeJS. I am already able to send notifications using token and the REST API:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#rest
I would like to use the topics feature, but it seems that the manage topics documentation does not contain a way to do it via REST:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics
Any suggestions?
